# Fibonacci with two functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I amb trying to create a Fibonacci sequence with two functions.
Can you tell me where am I wrong, please?

Thank you!

```
function aurea(quantitatNum){
    let numFibo = [];

    numFibo[0] = 0, numFibo[1] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i < quantitatNum; i++) {
        numFibo[i] = numFibo[i - 2] + numFibo[i - 1];
        numFibo.push(i); 
        numFibo.pop(quantitatNum); 
    }
    return aureaNum;
}

function calcular(){
    let quantitatNum = Number(document.getElementById("quantitatNum").value);
    let dadaCorrecta = Number.isInteger(quantitatNum) && quantitatNum > 0 ? true : false;
    let resposta = document.getElementById("resposta");
    let aureaNum;

    if (dadaCorrecta){
        aureaNum = aurea(quantitatNum);
        resposta.innerHTML = aureaNum;

    } else {
        resposta.innerHTML = "Error! Introdueix un valor enter positiu!";
    }
}
```

---

Well, at the begining I created the following structure and it works.
But when I tryied insert another function it didn't work...

```
function calcular(){
    let quantitatNum = Number(document.getElementById("quantitatNum").value);
    let dadaCorrecta = Number.isInteger(quantitatNum) && quantitatNum > 0 ? true : false;
    let resposta = document.getElementById("resposta");
    let numFibo = [];

    numFibo[0] = 0, numFibo[1] = 1;


    if (dadaCorrecta){
        for (i = 2; i < quantitatNum; i++) {
            numFibo[i] = numFibo[i - 2] + numFibo[i - 1];
            numFibo.push(i); 
            numFibo.pop(quantitatNum); 
        }
        resposta.innerHTML = numFibo;
    } else {
        resposta.innerHTML = "Error! Introdueix un valor enter positiu!";
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem you are having?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `.push` and `.pop` ?

Comment: `numFibo.pop(quantitatNum); ` does not make sense, it removes the item you just pushed in there

Comment: A possible way: https://gist.github.com/jfairbank/8d36e4bde9c16dc0bac7

Comment: The first function returns a variable that is not defined.

Comment: @NVRM, thank you but I prefere to solve this with my own code.

Comment: @Pointy, I do not understand that. I wrote "let aureaNum", isn't it?

Comment: @audreyhep82: you did, but it's in a different function, with a different scope.

Comment: @DavidThomas, could you please edit what are you telling me?

Comment: You define, and return, `aurea` in two unrelated functions; neither of which has access to the variables defined in the other.

Answer (score 3):

Some issues:

- `return aureNum` makes no sense: that is not a variable that is declared in `aurea`, nor has it participated in the calculation.
- `numFibo.push(i)`: why would you push the index in this array? The previous line already adds the i<sup>th</sup> value to the array.
- `pop` does not take an argument. No idea what you try to do here. However, *after* the loop, you could use `pop` to extract the last summed value and return it.
- Depending on how you number Fibonacci numbers, the loop should continue until `<=`.

Here is a corrected version:

```js
function aurea(quantitatNum){
    let numFibo = [];

    numFibo[0] = 0, numFibo[1] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= quantitatNum; i++) {
        numFibo[i] = numFibo[i - 2] + numFibo[i - 1];
    }
    return numFibo.pop();
}

function calcular(){
    let quantitatNum = Number(document.getElementById("quantitatNum").value);
    let dadaCorrecta = Number.isInteger(quantitatNum) && quantitatNum > 0 ? true : false;
    let resposta = document.getElementById("resposta");
    let aureaNum;

    if (dadaCorrecta){
        aureaNum = aurea(quantitatNum);
        resposta.innerHTML = aureaNum;

    } else {
        resposta.innerHTML = "Error! Introdueix un valor enter positiu!";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="quantitatNum"><button onclick="calcular()">Do</button>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```